# Quickly loading large data structures from a file

Tags: c++, algorithm, serialization, data-structures, trie

I have a large dictionary of english words (around 70k of them) that I load into memory at the beginning of the program. They are loaded into a radix trie data structure, and each trie node often has many links from one node to many others (for example the word antonyms, "dead" -> "alive", "well"). Each node also have a `std::vector<MetaData>` in it which contains various miscellaneous metadata for my program.

Now, the problem is with the loading time of this file. Reading the file from disk, deserialization and allocating the data structure for the thing in general takes a lot of time (4-5 seconds).

Currently, I'm working on making the load asynchronously (or bit by bit, a fraction of them per frame), but due to the nature of the application (it's a mobile keyboard), there's just plenty of times where it simply has to be loaded quickly.

What can be done to speed up loading? Memory pool everything? I am benchmarking different parts to see what can be optimized, but it looks like, so far, it's just little things that add up.

Comment: This is also architecture dependent, can you seek and read a specific part of the file?

Comment: You can, I think.. though I can load the whole serialized data to memory first. After benchmarking, that part is rather quick and is not the bottleneck.

Comment: If you don't somehow need the entire datastructure at once (i.e. you don't know where it will "hit"), you might just "bake" some offsets to the part of the data you're interested and load a structure into memory with the word->offset_to_data. That would be quicker. You can preprocess the stuff before launching your application as well

Comment: With Qs like this one, with lots of important detals missing, it's dfficult to help. - Seems I got ups and downs, no explanation, though...

Comment: How are you handing the bit by bit loading. Rather than put the dictionary in a single file, spreading it out over a number (possibly hundreds or even thousands) of roughly equal sized files. Add in a bit of rough optimization work to ensure that required information tends to be in the same file and chances are you'll only need to load a file or two per frame. What user is typing/doing should give you what you need to determine which file(s) to load. Pretty much how some video games handle it if I recall. Thomas Matthews gives a good starting point for organization via tables as files.

Comment: How much time does it take just to read complete file into memory? Is this time acceptable to you?

Comment: @Dialecticus loading the complete file doesn't take long, it's deserializing them into actual data structures with lots of references.

Comment: @Nuclearman with bit by bit loading, I'll just load the whole serialized file into memory and load parts of them over time, as opposed as doing it completely at once, which takes a long time. This way the keyboard can pop up first, giving the impression of a "fast" load.

Comment: @laune yeah, I saw your answer get -1, but I bumped it up to zero. Maybe the stackoverflow meta?

Comment: It would be interesting to compare this (or an improved) version with a straightforward Collection-based approach, with the data - including the cross references - stored in XML, unmarshalling with JAXB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the trie is static (i.e. doesn't change when the program's running), then build an optimized version in an array using array indexes in place of pointers. You can then save that as your data file. Startup then amounts to just loading that block of data into memory.

Doing it that way makes some things less convenient (you'll have to use arrays rather than `std::vector`, for example), and you might have to do a bit of casting, but with a little thought you end up with a very compact and very fast data structure that doesn't suffer from the allocation overhead associated with creating an object for each node. Instead, it's essentially an array of varying length structures.

I did this for an application that used a directed acyclic word graph (DAWG). Rather than rebuild the DAWG every time the program was loaded (a time consuming process), I had a utility program that created the DAWG and shipped that as the data file in place of the word list.

Comment: Hmm, that's a good idea. If only it's easy to replace all the links to use indices though, but I suppose this is not in the realm of impossibility.

Comment: I have to add that the trie does change from time to time, but if everything uses indexes instead of pointers, and are located in a contiguous point in memory, then I guess that would simply be memory loading huh?

Comment: @kamziro: If it changes while the program is running, then you need to allocate a larger array. Or have the array already allocated for growth. It's not an insurmountable problem, but something to think about.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing the details, only a vague idea:

Loading the bulk data (entries) will give you the basic dictionary.

For all the cross references like syn- and antonyms and whatever, load and process the data in background, after you've shown "ready". Chances are, until A. User has typed in the first query, you are ship-shape.

**Later**

If the file is rather big, reading a compressed version may gain.

Also, a BufferedReader with a suitably increased buffer size may help.

Answer (score 1):

You should review the structure of the data to make the data faster to load.
Also, splitting into multiple tables may speed things up.

For example, have one table for the words, another table for synonyms and additional tables for other relationships.

The first table should have  organization.  This allows the synonym table to be represented as ; which should load fast.

You can then build any internal containers from the data loaded in.  A reason for having different data structures for store data vs. internal data is for optimization.  The structures used for data storage (and loading) are optimized for loading.  The structure for internal data is optimized for searching.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea based on the fact that it is a mobile keyboard application.
Some words are used more often than others, so maybe you could organize it so the frequently used words are loaded first and leave the infrequently used ones to be loaded as it is needed (or as you have time).